# How can I make my function work as planned? Is my logic wrong? (LONG)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Sorry for the vague/"personal" question. I'm having a hard time figuring out why my code isn't working like I want it to. In essence, my program is a math game. I'm trying to make a "re-quiz" function which makes you redo math problems you got wrong.

So I have a function called addition:

```
function addition()  { //addition function

 function generateNumber() { //generateNumber is a function that creates 2 numbers based on the user's input from cookies
 var n1= Math.floor(Math.random() * (cookiearray[2] - cookiearray[1]) + cookiearray[1]);  //n1 is equal to a random number between the user input. It grabs values from the cookie array.
 var n2= Math.floor(Math.random() * (cookiearray[2] - cookiearray[1]) + cookiearray[1]); //n2 is also a random number.
 document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = n1 + " + " + n2 + "=" ; //this asks the user the question
 window.answer = n1+n2;

 } //end of generateNumber function

 generateNumber(); //calls the generateNumber function.


 }
```

This function just makes 2 random numbers and asks you to add it. Now, to have the computer know the answer, I made the it store the answer as a global variable called "answer".

Then, I used jQuery to evaluate the answer. If the key enter is pressed, then it checks if the answer is equal to what the user inputted. If it was wrong, then the computer puts the question into an array and the answer to that question in another array:

```
$("#input").keyup(function(event){ //targets the input box
if(event.keyCode == 13){ //when enter is pressed


    if(answer == $('#input').val()){ //evaluate if the input value was equal to the global variable answer (from game.js)

     //if it is the correct answer...


     score += 1; //add score by 1
     document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score ; //print score

      addition();
     $('#input').val('') //clears text box for next question

  } 

  else {
     //if the input answer was incorrect...

  requizQuestions.push(display1);
  requizAnswers.push(answer);
  document.getElementById("incorrect").innerHTML +=  "<br />" + "The answer to " + display1 + " was " + answer + " not " + $('#input').val();
  addition();
  $('#input').val('') //clears text box for next question

  }


} //end if statement (with keycode)
```

Either way, when the user gets it right/wrong, the addition function is called again.

Now, my REAL PROBLEM is how to display the problem and make it "overwrite" what the addition function created (a variable called answer and the question). How should I create a function that does this? The code I have currently doesn't do that...

```
function requiz() {
var i = 0;
window.answer = requizAnswers[i];
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = requizQuestions[i];

 $("#input").keyup(function(event){ //targets the input box
if(event.keyCode == 13){ //when enter is pressed


  if(answer === $('#input').val()){ //evaluate if the input value was equal to the global variable answer (from game.js)


  i+=1;
  window.answer = requizAnswers[i];
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = requizQuestions[i];   


  } else {
//didn't know what to put here  
  }



} //end if statement (with keycode)





   });


   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd take a slightly different approach. Generate all your questions and their answers up front, andd store in an array. Then, remove a question from the array and show it to the user--if they answer incorrectly then add the question to the back of the list. Once the array is empty, then the quiz is over. Here's a working sample:

```js
var questions = [];
var question = null;
var min, max;

function startGame() {
  min = Number(prompt("Enter your min value", 0));
  max = Number(prompt("Enter your max value", 10));
  let numberOfQuestions = Number(prompt("Enter number of questions", 5));

  //pre-create all questions
  for(let i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
    questions.push(generateNumber());
  }

  askNext();
}

function askNext() {
  //clear the answer box
  $("#answer").val("");

  //update the question
  if (questions.length > 0) {
    //get the next question out of the array
    question = questions.shift();
    $("#question").text(question.question);
  } else {
    $("#question").text("Done");
  }
}

function generateNumber() { //generateNumber is a function that creates 2 numbers based on the user's input from cookies
  var n1= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);  //n1 is equal to a random number between the user input. It grabs values from the cookie array.
  var n2= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //n2 is also a random number.
  var question = n1 + " + " + n2 + " = " ; //this asks the user the question
  var answer = n1+n2;
  return {
    question : question,
    answer : answer
  };
}

$(function() {
  startGame();
  $("#answer").on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      //get the number the user entered
      let answer = Number(this.value);

      //if it's wrong, add to the end of the question list
      if (answer !== question.answer)
        questions.push(question);

      //continue with the next question
      askNext();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="question">
</span>
<input id="answer" />
```